# Get the val() of textarea within a foreach of php with a button in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Get the val() of textarea within a foreach of php with a button in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boton_responder').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr("name");
        var texto = $('input[name="'+cod+'"]' ).val();   
        console.log(texto);  
    });
});
```

it's for a system of comment in html with php and jquery, just that when an admin is logged in the system, show all the comments without answers and will show a field textarea for that the admin will write the answers.

So, i'm stop here because in console.log in texto show indefined, but "cod" show fine the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select is incorrect. Try:

```
var texto = $('textarea[name="'+cod+'"]').val();
```